# How to run computations for n seconds in Julia?

Tags: julia

I'd like to run heavy computations in Julia for a fixed duration, for example 10 seconds. I tried this:

```
timer = Timer(10.0)
while isopen(timer)
    computation()
end
```

But this does not work, since the computations never let Julia's task scheduler take control. So I added `yield()` in the loop:

```
timer = Timer(10.0)
while isopen(timer)
    yield()
    computation()
end
```

But now there is significant overhead from calling `yield()`, especially when one call to `computation()` is short. I guess I could call `yield()` and `isopen()` only every 1000 iterations or so, but I would prefer a solution where I would not have to tweak the number of iterations every time I change the computations. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you expect each execution of `computation` to take approximately the same duration ?

Comment: Yes, roughly the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern below uses threads and on my laptop has a latency of around 35ms for each 1,000,000 calls which is more than acceptable for any job.

Tested on Julia 1.5 release candidate:

```
function should_stop(timeout=10)
    handle = Threads.Atomic{Bool}(false)
    mytask = Threads.@spawn begin
        sleep(timeout)
        Threads.atomic_or!(handle, true)
    end
    handle
end


function do_some_job_with_timeout()
    handle = should_stop(5)
    res = BigInt() # save results to some object
    mytask = Threads.@spawn begin
        for i in 1:10_000_000
            #TODO some complex computations here
            res += 1 # mutate the result object
            handle.value && break
        end
    end
    wait(mytask) # wait for the job to complete
    res
end
```

You can also used `Distributed` instead. The code below seems to have a much better latency - only about 1ms for each 1,000,000 timeout checks.

```
using Distributed
using SharedArrays
addprocs(1)
function get_termination_handle(timeout=5,workerid::Int=workers()[end])::SharedArray{Bool}
    handle = SharedArray{Bool}([false])
    proc = @spawnat workerid begin
        sleep(timeout)
        handle[1]=true
    end
    handle
end


function fun_within_timeout()
    res = 0
    h = get_termination_handle(0.1)
    for i = 1:100_000_000
        res += i % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0
        h[1] && break
    end
    res
end
```

Comment: Thanks Przemyslaw Szufel, but unfortunately I cannot get this to work. If I run it as is, the computations are finished after 2 seconds on my computer. If I bump up the iteration to 1:10^9, the computations do not stop after 5 seconds. If I add `yield()` in the loop, then it works. I suspect that both sleep & loop tasks get scheduled in the same thread. Note that I did set JULIA_NUM_THREADS=16 before starting Julia. Also note that I tried running the job in the main thread rather than a second Thread.@spawn, but it made no difference.

Comment: What Julia version you have? I have been testing it in Julia 1.5 rc1. This code worked for me only when these are two separate threads (hence that is why I spawn twice). You could perhaps try to add another variable and store `Threads.threadid()` to see if they get spawned separately. As fat as I know there is no method to select threadid so if this does not help I will propose code using `Distributed`.

Comment: I'm using 1.4.2. I'll give 1.5 rc1 a try.

Comment: I added the `Distributed` code. It also seems to have much lower latency.

Comment: Thanks for the distributed version, it seems to work in Julia 1.4.2. Also, I can confirm that the 1st solution works for me when using 1.5rc1. However, the distributed version does not work for me in 1.5rc1, this is weird.

Comment: I implemented and tested the `Distributed` version in Julia 1.5rc1. While the threading API is changing between versions the `Distributed` API is stable. Perhaps you forgot the `addprocs` command?

Comment: I just double-checked, I can confirm that the distributed version does not work for me on MacBook 10.15.5 with 1.15.rc1, but it works with 1.14.2. The only thing I changed in your code is the iteration length: up to 100_000_000_000 instead of 100_000_000 (or else the loop ends too fast).

Comment: I do not own a Mac to check but this sounds like a bug to me. Perhaps you do not have a separate JULIA_DEPOT_PATH for 1.5rc1 installed on the same machien. What happens when you use SharedArray{Int}([0]) and update the code accordingly. One processes should always immediately see the changes made to the `SharedArray` made by the other.